# pgf-umlsd: sdblock around right aligned call (multi-thread)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I have this snippet of tex...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage[a1paper,portrait]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\section{Use Case 1: Imbalance Settlement and Resistors}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[bottom color=white, top color=white]
        \newthread{ecp}{:ECP}{}
        \newinst[1]{eap}{:EAP}{}
        \newinst[1]{stream}{:STREAM}{}
        %\newinst[1]{db}{:DATABASE}{}
        \newinst[1]{spf}{:SPF}{}
        \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[bottom color=white, top color=white]
        \newinst[1]{rtu}{:RTU}{}
        \newthread{operator}{:OPERATOR}{}
        \begin{sdblock}{loop}{[for each PTU]}
            \begin{sdblock}{loop}{[continuous]}
                \begin{call}{ecp}{getSPF}{stream}{SPF}
                    \begin{call}{stream}{getSPF}{spf}{SPF}
                    \end{call}      
                    \postlevel
                \end{call}
                \prelevel \prelevel
                setthreadbias{east}
                \begin{call}{operator}{getSPF}{stream}{SPF}
                    \postlevel
                \end{call}
                
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sdblock}
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It returns the next result (not including the red rectangle):
[image]

Question:
How to put an sdblock (or maybe another square) at the location of the red square?

Answer (score 1):

`pgf-umlsd` creates various nodes named depending on the level. You can make use of those, along with some manual tweaking, to make such a box. For example if you add `\usetikzlibrary{fit}` you can use

```
\node [fit=(cf1)(rt1),draw,red,very thick,inner ysep=2mm,yshift=1.5mm] {};
```

Or without any libraries:

```
\draw [red, very thick] ([shift={(10pt,11pt)}]cf1.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-10pt,-2pt)}]rt1.south east);
```

Add either of these just before `\end{sequencediagram}`.

For a `call` between two different things, you get nodes called `cfN`, `ctN`, `rfN` and `rtN`, where `N` is an integer. For a `call` going back to the same thing, you get nodes called `scN`, `scbN`, `sceN` and `sctN`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[bottom color=white, top color=white]
        \newthread{ecp}{:ECP}{}
        \newinst[1]{eap}{:EAP}{}
        \newinst[1]{stream}{:STREAM}{}
        %\newinst[1]{db}{:DATABASE}{}
        \newinst[1]{spf}{:SPF}{}
        \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[bottom color=white, top color=white]
        \newinst[1]{rtu}{:RTU}{}
        \newthread{operator}{:OPERATOR}{}
        \begin{sdblock}{loop}{[for each PTU]}
            \begin{sdblock}{loop}{[continuous]}
                \begin{call}{ecp}{getSPF}{stream}{SPF}
                    \begin{call}{stream}{getSPF}{spf}{SPF}
                    \end{call}      
                    \postlevel
                \end{call}
                \prelevel \prelevel
                setthreadbias{east}
                \begin{call}{operator}{getSPF}{stream}{SPF}
                    \postlevel
                \end{call}
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sdblock}
        \node [fit=(cf1)(rt1),draw,red,very thick,inner ysep=2mm,yshift=1.5mm] {};
        %\draw [red, very thick] ([shift={(10pt,11pt)}]cf1.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-10pt,-2pt)}]rt1.south east);
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you!